# Creating proportions from two queries in sql

Tags: mysql

The query:

```
SELECT year, count(*) as total FROM table GROUP BY year
```

gives me a list of totals per year, such as:

```
year total
2000 100
2001 120
2002 124
2003 156
```

Whereas the query:

```
SELECT year, count(*) as male FROM table WHERE gender='Male' GROUP BY year
```

gives me a list of totals just for the Males per year, such as:

```
year male
2000 50
2001 55
2002 60
2003 70
```

What I desire are the proportions per year: that is `male/total` to give as output:

```
year prop
2000 0.50
2001 0.46
2002 0.48
2003 0.45
```

How can this be done with one MySql query?

Comment: Can you provide some sample table data and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with a conditional sum something as

```
select
year,
count(*) as total,
sum(gender='Male') as male_count,
( sum(gender='Male') / count(*)  ) as proportions
from table 
GROUP BY year
```

For your output format its

```
select
year,
( sum(gender='Male') / count(*)  ) as prop
from table 
GROUP BY year
```